# How to create an attribute, getter, and setter for date in java?

Tags: java, date, attributes, getter-setter

How would you put create an attribute of a class that is a date? I'm looking to make a start date an attribute, but am struggling with syntax

```
public class Adventure{
     private String Location;
     private int cost;
     private Localdate startDate;

     public void Setdate(int year, int month, int day){
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
     }
     public LocalDate getDate(){
        return startDate;
     }
}
```

For some reason, this isn't working for me. The first 2 private attributes can be ignored, but i'm just trying to do a getter and setter for a date attribute

Comment: why don't you use `LocalDate` as parameter type, i.e. why don't you use: `void setStartDate(LocalDate date) { this.startDate = date; }`?

Comment: Replace ``LocalDate startDate = `` with ``startDate = ``.

Comment: FWIW, " isn't working for me" is not a good error description - java is very chatty on reporting errors (either at compile time or runtime)!

Comment: @f1sh @ Roland Thank you guys! I'll incorporate these

Comment: For start, `private Localdate startDate;` should be `private LocalDate startDate;`

Comment: By the way, design tip: Since `LocalDate` is a built-in data type, your class could reasonably expect the calling code to pass a formed `LocalDate` instance rather than taking and validating the year-month-day arguments. `public void setdate( LocalDate localDate ){ this.startDate = localDate ; }`

Comment: Beware of case of names of methods and types. According to conventions a method name begins with a small letter, so `setDate` with lowercase `s`. And `LocalDate` has an uppercase `D` in it, you got it right most of the times, only missed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code does not work is because in `SetDate` method you are setting
value to new variable instead of class variable.

class variable  -

```
//accessible to all (non-static)method in class
private Localdate startDate;
```

method variable -

```
 //only available inside the SetDate method
 LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```

In short, both are different

You can do something like this to make it working

```
 public void Setdate(int year, int month, int day){
    this.startDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
 }
```

Comment: Thank! I'll put this in now

Comment: i just did, sorry. I'm new to Stackoverflow and just learning now

Comment: @LiamKr its ok, I know that !